# JavaScript Standard Library for V8

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

In my application, I allow users to write plugins using JavaScript. I embed V8 for that purpose. The problem is that developers can't use things like HTTP, Sockets, Streams, Timers, Threading, Crypotography, Unit tests, et cetra.

I searched Stack Overflow and I found node.js. The problem with it is that you can actually **create** HTTP servers, and start processes and more things that I do not want to allow. In addition, node.js has its own environment (`./node script.js`) and you can't embed it. And it doesn't support Windows - I need it to be fully cross platform. If those problems can be solved, it will be awesome :) But I'm open to other frameworks too.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I built my own library.

Comment: cool.. Any of that is open source? I am starting on similar project and would be great to look at that. Also is there any standard library docs for v8 available?

Answer (score 3):

There is [CommonJS](http://commonjs.org/), which defines a "standard" and a [few implementations available](http://commonjs.org/impl/) of that standard - one of which is node.js.

But from what I can see, it's still fairly immature and there aren't many "complete" implementations.